# Building capicxx-core-runtime for Android

Tags: android, embedded-linux, android-build

We are trying to build `capicxx-core-runtime` for an ARM based platform running Android Pie. It's an open source IPC framework which is part of the GENIVI initiative by major automotive OEM's. Our AIM is to bring the IPC framework into our Android system.

The git repo is placed here https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-core-runtime.git

I am using the Android NDK version r17b and building using the following command to configure the cmake based build.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/hp/downloads/android-ndk-r17b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=27 ../
```

When I compile using 'make', I see the individual cpp files are compiled, but I am getting following errors during linking as shown in the link below.What is the configuration that I may be missing.

[Linker error log](https://gist.github.com/gehariprasath/a96d8709f411ab5b988e7801c2349d66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the capicxx-core-runtime is building a shared library, so you need to resolve all of it's internal symbols, including the c++ runtime.

To quickly test this: edit the capicxx-core-runtime CMakeLists.txt to link the c++_shared runtime, line 130:

```
target_link_libraries(CommonAPI PRIVATE ${DL_LIBRARY} ${DLT_LIBRARIES})
```

becomes

```
target_link_libraries(CommonAPI PRIVATE ${DL_LIBRARY} ${DLT_LIBRARIES} c++_shared)
```

and rerun your cmake command and make command.

Comment: I am able to proceed with the build and shared library is generated. Is it possible to build both static and shared library at the same time ?

Comment: Not without a lot of editing of the cmake. But to build static, run cmake with -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF. To build shared, just run as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that capicxx-core-runtime can be buildable now for Android (both NDK and AOSP) out the box, please see corresponding pull requests: https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-core-runtime/pulls?q=author%3Ankh-lab+

Also here is simple example for AndroidStudio how it could be used with vSOME/IP transport: https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-capi-hello-world